# Thymeleaf: XSL transformation on a XML document

Tags: xml, jsp, xslt, jstl, thymeleaf

Using Thymeleaf, how to transform xml into html. In jsp we can use x:transform jstl tag.

What is Thymeleaf equivalent of below jsp code:

```
<c:import url="/data/book.xml" var="inputvalue" />
<c:import url="/styles/book.xsl" var="stylesheet" />

<x:transform xml="${inputvalue}" xslt="${stylesheet}">
    <x:param name="bid" value="${bookId}" />
</x:transform>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I did not find exact replacement of x:transform in Thymeleaf.

However, I have found couple of ways to use xsl with Thymeleaf or any other template engine or without any template engine:

1) we can create html String on server side using xsl processor such as Saxon. And then show it on the ui:

```
<P th:utext="${bookHtml}"></P>
```

2) We can use XsltViewResolver in Spring.

3) We can write javascript code to transform xml into html as [explained here](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/xsl_client.asp)

4) Most browsers transform xml to html using xslt mentioned in xml like this:

```
<?xml-stylesheet type="text/xsl" href="book.xsl" ?>
```

Comment: I was checking if I could use Thymeleaf on a project with xml and xsl, and this answer motivated me to do so. Thank You! :)